# Xcode 10.2 detects memory leaks in a new single view app

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode10, xcode-instruments

Can anyone reproduce memory leaks in a **new** and **unchanged** single view app created with Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001) / Swift 5 / iOS 12.2 ? How to work seriously with the integrated memory leak tool? Are there any workarounds?

**The first image shows 1 memory leak (iPhone 8)**
[image]

**The second image shows 37 memory leaks (iPhone Xr simulator)**
[image]

**NOTE**

The amount of leaks vary every time I start the analyzer tool.

**EDIT 1**

I noticed, that Xcode 10 uses a new build system. Maybe the issues are based on this.
[Build System Release Notes for Xcode 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10)

**EDIT 2**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174297/new-empty-ios-app-has-dozens-of-memory-leaks?rq=1) seems to be very similar to mine.

Comment: What’s the question? — Seems the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174297/new-empty-ios-app-has-dozens-of-memory-leaks?rq=1

Comment: Puhh what a dump, sorry for that duplicate. I didn't noticed this post.

Comment: ...but you are right. Just confirmed with Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)

Comment: And the bug is bag again in Xcode 11.0 -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is solved with the new Xcode 10.3 [release](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_3_release_notes)!

> Resolved an issue where running an app in iOS 12.2 or later under the
>   Leaks instrument resulted in random numbers of false-positive leaks
>   for every leak check after the first one in a given run. (48549361)